# Duplicate each row on DataFrame based on an input Value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm beginner in Spark Scala. I want to duplicate each row in my DataFrame based on an input value.

My Input Dataset is something liks this

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|id          |currency             |value                |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|1           |USD                  |10                   |
|1           |EUR                  |20                   |
|2           |USD                  |30                   |
|2           |EUR                  |40                   |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And my Input Value is a Sequence. for example Seq("JPY"). I want an output like this:

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|id          |currency             |value                |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|1           |USD                  |10                   |
|1           |EUR                  |20                   |

|2           |USD                  |30                   |
|2           |EUR                  |40                   |

|1           |JPY                  |10                   |
|1           |JPY                  |20                   |

|2           |JPY                  |30                   |
|2           |JPY                  |40                   |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Could someOne please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append seq and then use explode and union with original df

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val inputData = Seq((1, "USD", 10), (1, "EUR", 20), (2, "USD", 30), (2, "EUR", 40))
val inputSeq = Seq("JPY")

val originalDf = inputData.toDF("id", "currency", "value")
val originalDfWithSequence = originalDf.withColumn("currencies_seq", typedLit(inputSeq))
val originalDfExploded = originalDfWithSequence.select(col("id"), explode(col("currencies_seq")).alias("currency"), col("value") )
originalDf.union(originalDfExploded).show()
```

Outpus is:

```
+---+--------+-----+
| id|currency|value|
+---+--------+-----+
|  1|     USD|   10|
|  1|     EUR|   20|
|  2|     USD|   30|
|  2|     EUR|   40|
|  1|     JPY|   10|
|  1|     JPY|   20|
|  2|     JPY|   30|
|  2|     JPY|   40|
+---+--------+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating another duplicate dataframe overrwite the currency column, then union the 2 dataframes:

```
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq(
  ("1", "USD", "10"),
  ("1", "EUR", "20"),
  ("2", "USD", "30"),
  ("2", "EUR", "40")
).toDF("id", "currency", "value")

df.union(df.withColumn("currency", lit("JPY"))).show(false)

+---+--------+-----+
|id |currency|value|
+---+--------+-----+
|1  |USD     |10   |
|1  |EUR     |20   |
|2  |USD     |30   |
|2  |EUR     |40   |
|1  |JPY     |10   |
|1  |JPY     |20   |
|2  |JPY     |30   |
|2  |JPY     |40   |
+---+--------+-----+
```